# How to redirect a URL with GET variables in routes.rb without Rails stripping out the variable first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rack, http-status-code-301

I am building a website in Rails to replace an existing website. In `routes.rb` I am trying to redirect some of the old URLs to their new equivalents (some of the URL slugs are changing so a dynamic solution is not possible.)

My `routes.rb` looks like this:

```
  match "/index.php?page=contact-us" => redirect("/contact-us")
  match "/index.php?page=about-us" => redirect("/about-us")
  match "/index.php?page=committees" => redirect("/teams")
```

When I visit `/index.php?page=contact-us` I am not redirected to `/contact-us`. I have determined this is because Rails is removing the get variables and only trying to match `/index.php`. For example, If I pass `/index.php?page=contact-us` into the below routes I will be redirected to `/foobar`:

```
  match "/index.php?page=contact-us" => redirect("/contact-us")
  match "/index.php?page=about-us" => redirect("/about-us")
  match "/index.php?page=committees" => redirect("/teams")
  match "/index.php" => redirect("/foobar")
```

How can I keep the GET variables in the string and redirect the old URLs the way I'd like? Does Rails have an intended mechanism for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar situation, this is what I did:

Create a controller taking care of redirects with one action

```
RedirectController < ApplicationController
  def redirect_url
    if params[:page]
      redirect_to "/#{params[:page]}", :status => 301
    else
      raise 404 #how handle your 404
  end
end
```

**In routes.rb**

```
match "/index.php" => "redirect#redirect_url"
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an excellent solution. I only made one change, which was to name the controller action something else like redirect_url. If it is named redirect_to then ruby tries to call the controller method redirect_to instead of the existing redirection method and breaks the app.

Comment: Ok, I did the change. Thanks.